Why are these ergodic measures linearly independent?
I am trying to understand the proof of Proposition 3.1 "Sur l'unique ergodicité des 1-formes fermées singulières" by Arnoux and Levitt. This is in French so I will give a (possibly incorrect, as I don't speak French) translation below.
In the proof they have finitely many ergodic probability measures $\mu^j_i$ and some coefficients $a_i^j$ which satisfy $\mu_i^+ = \mu_i^-$ where $\mu_i^+ := \sum_{j:a^j_i > 0} a^j_i \mu^j_i$ and $\mu_i^- := \sum_{j:a^j_i < 0} |a^j_i| \mu^j_i$. The $\mu^j_i$ are pairwise linearly independent. From this they conclude $a^j_i = 0$.
Now I don't think the hypothesis that they are ergodic probability measures is particularly important. So this really does just seem to be a linear algebra problem, and I give a simplified version:

Suppose that for some linear functional $p$ on a finite-dimensional real vector space $V$, coefficients $a_i$, and pairwise linearly independent vectors $\mu_i$, we have $p(\mu_i) = 1$, and if $\mu^+ := \sum_{i:a_i > 0} a_i \mu_i$ and $\mu^- := \sum_{i:a_i < 0} |a_i| \mu_i$, then $\mu^+ = \mu^-$. Then $a_i = 0$.

Presumably this is an easy algebra problem if it's correct (and if it's not, then I don't see how Proposition 3.1 could be true). But I'm a provincial analyst who bumbled my way through algebra in uni and early graduate school, so I am very stuck.
EDIT: Per the first answer, the crossed-out text is incorrect: we must be using that they are probability measures somehow. I don't know how, so: why are $a^j_i = 0$?
And here is my attempted translation of the relevant part of the paper (omitting the parts only relevant to Proposition 3.4).

... choose representatives $\mu_i^j$ of the proportional classes of ergodic transverse measures on $\omega|_{U_i}$. Each $\mu_i^j$ is associated to a homomorphism $[\mu_i^j]$ from $H_1(M, \mathbb Z)$ to $\mathbb R$. [They then construct $q_i \in \mathbb Q$ and a homomorphism $t_i: H_1(M, \mathbb Z) \to q_i \mathbb Z$, with some properties that aren't too important to this discussion.]
To prove Proposition 3.1, given that $t_i$ satisfies the properties above, it suffices to show that the family formed by the $[\mu_i^j]$ and $t_i$ is linearly independent in $H^1(M, \mathbb R)$. Suppose that $a_i^j$ and $b_i$ are real numbers such that
$$\sum_{i, j} a_i^j [\mu_i^j](\alpha) + \sum_i b_i t_i = 0$$
for every $\alpha \in H_1(M, \mathbb Z)$. We must show that the real numbers are all zero.
Let $C$ be an oriented curve in $U_i$. Since
$$\sum_i a_i^j [\mu_i^j](C) + b_i t_i(C) = 0,$$
we have $\sum_j a_i^j [\mu_i^j](C) \in b_i q_i \mathbb Z$. Let $\mu_i^+ = \sum_j a^j_i \mu_i^j$, the summation taken over the $j$s such that $a_i^j > 0$, and the same for $\mu_i^-$. Then
$$[\mu_i^+](C) - [\mu_i^-](C) \in b_i q_i \mathbb Z$$
for every curve $C \subset U_i$, so by [the previous lemma], $\mu_i^+ = \mu_i^-$. The $\mu_i^j$ are distinct [I think -- the text is "étrangères les unes aux autres", literally "foreign to each other"] so this is only possible if, for every $j$, $a_i^j = 0$.


Counterexample:
In $\mathbb R^2$ try $\mu_1 = (1,0)$, $\mu_2 = (0,1)$, $\mu_3 = (1/2,1/2)$.  These are pairwise linearly independent and $p(\mu_i) = 1$ where $p((x,y)) = x + y$.  Take $a_1 = a_2 = 1$ and $a_3 = -2$ so $\mu^+ =  \mu_1 + \mu_2 = (1,1)$ and $\mu^- = 2 \mu_3 = (1,1)$.

Well that's embarassingly easy. I'll reword the question to ask what's going on in the Arnoux--Levitt proof, since it's apparently not linear algebra.
